# Google QR code generator has extra whitespace with length

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-visualization

I use the Google Chart APIs to generate QR codes in an HTML file used by Google Apps Script:

```
<img src='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fa%2Fforms%2Fd%2F1c0pS0jHY2O2dtLBddqm9myllAh8Lo8Ej_KyvHCYvxzQ%2Fviewform%3Fentry.936466191%3D<?!= data[6] ?>' alt='QR code' height='150' width='150' />
```

This worked well, generating QR codes like: [Good QR Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXjBw.png)

[image]

When I added another parameter however, extra whitespace around the QR code appeared, like: [Bad QR code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj5iY.png)

[image]

```
<img src='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fa%2Fforms%2Fd%2F1c0pS0jHY2O2dtLBddqm9myllAh8Lo8Ej_KyvHCYvxzQ%2Fviewform%3Fentry.1155899134%3DCheck%2BIn%2FOut%26entry.936466191%3D<?!= data[6] ?>' alt='QR code' height='150' width='150' />
```

Other than the extra parameter, there was no change. How could I get rid of the excess whitespace? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the extra bits in your second QR code are enough to bump it up to a higher QR version (http://www.qrcode.com/en/about/version.html) with more modules.

Try running your encoded URL through a URL shortener first if you want consistent, small, easy-to-decode QR codes.

Comment: How could URL shorteners accept the variable argument? Thanks

Comment: Goo.gl, Bit.ly and others have APIs you can use where, once set up, you send a long URL and receive a shortened URL via PHP / CURL. http://dev.bitly.com/get_started.html https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started